# In grails PromiseMap, how to block current thread, for all of the concurrent tasks to complete and return their results?

Tags: asynchronous, grails3

I need to asynchronously fetch cats, dogs and mice and then do some post-processing. Here is something what I am doing:

```
Promise<List<Cat>> fetchCats  = task {}
Promise<List<Mouse>> fetchMice  = task { }
Promise<List<Dog>> fetchDogs  = task {}
List promiseList = [fetchCats, fetchMice, fetchDogs]
List results = Promises.waitAll(promiseList)
```

The problem I am facing is, order of items in list `results` is not fixed, i.e. in one execution results can be `[cats, dogs, mice]` and in other execution, results can be `[dogs, mice, cats]`.

Which means to access `cats` I need to explicitly check type of element of `results`, and similarly for `dogs`, and `mice` which makes my code look bad.

Upon going through documentation [here](https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/async.html), I found `PromiseMap` API can help me as it provides a pretty way of accessing results through key-value pairs. Here is what it offers:

```
import grails.async.*

def map = new PromiseMap()
map['one'] = { 2 * 2 }
map['two'] = { 4 * 4 }
map['three'] = { 8 * 8 }
map.onComplete { Map results ->
  assert [one:4,two:16,three:64] == results
}
```

Though `PromiseMap` has an `onComplete` method, but it does not make current thread wait for all the promises to finish.

Using `PromiseMap`, how can I block the current thread till all the promises get finished?

Answer (score 1):

If you are only concern about current thread to wait until PromiseMap complete, can use Thread : join()

```
import grails.async.*

def map = new PromiseMap()

map['one'] = { println "task one" }
map['two'] = { println "task two" }
map['three'] = { println "task three" }

Thread t = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        println("pausing the current thread, let promiseMap complete first")
        map.onComplete { Map results ->
            println("Promisemap processing : " + results)
        }
    }
}

t.start()
t.join()

println("\n  CurrentThread : I can won the race if you just comment t.join() line in code")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.get()`

From the PromiseMap source:

> ```
> /**
>  * Synchronously return the populated map with all values obtained from promises used
>  * inside the populated map
>  *
>  * @return A map where the values are obtained from the promises
>  */
> Map<K, V> get() throws Throwable {
> ```